# asp.net Must Declare The Scalar Variable @Name?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net

I'm trying to submit data to a SQL Server database and I'm getting this error:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Must declare the scalar variable "@Name".

But my variable matches the one placed at the parameter ...

Please help:

```
protected void onclickregiPatient(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con = new SqlConnection(conString);
    con.Open();

    if (FileUploadControl.HasFile)
    {
        string Name = txtName.Text;
        string surname = txtSurname.Text;
        string gender = genderRadio.Text;
        string dob = txtDob.Text;
        string dop = txtPob.Text;
        string nationality = txtNationality.Text;
        string birthcert = txtBirthCert.Text;
        string nationalid = txtNationalID.Text;
        string occupation = txtOccupation.Text;
        byte[] photo = FileUploadControl.FileBytes;
        string blood = DropDownList1.Text;
        string eye = eyeColor.Text;
        string skin = txtSkinColr.Text;
        string height = txtHeight.Text;
        string status = txtHivstatus.Text;
        string phone = txtPhone.Text;
        string posaddress = txtPosAddress.Text;
        string physicaladdress = txtPhyAddress.Text;
        string fullname = txtFullName.Text;
        string relationship = txtRelationship.Text;
        string phoneno = txtphoneNo.Text;
        string postal = postalAddres.Text;
        string physical = physicalAddress.Text;
        string radio = RadioButtonList1.Text;
        string type = txtType.Text;

        string insertSQL = ("insert into patientProfile values(@Name, @surname, @gender, @dob, @dop, @nationality, @birthcert, @nationalid, @occupation, @photo, @blood, @eye, @skin, @height, @status, @phone, @posaddress, @physicaladdress, @fullname, @relationship, @phoneno, @postal, @physical, @radio, @type)");
        cmd = new SqlCommand(insertSQL, con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Name;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@surname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = surname;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@gender", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = gender;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@dob", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dob;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@dop", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dop;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@nationality", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = nationality;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@birthcert", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = birthcert;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@nationalid", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = nationalid;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@occupation", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = occupation;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@photo", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = photo;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@blood", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = blood;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@eye", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = eye;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@skin", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = skin;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@height", SqlDbType.Int).Value = height;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@status", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = status;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@phone", SqlDbType.Int).Value = phone;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@posaddress", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = posaddress;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@physicaladdress", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = physicaladdress;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@relationship", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = relationship;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@phoneno", SqlDbType.Int).Value = phoneno;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@postal", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = postal;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@physical", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = physical;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@radio", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = radio;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@type", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = type;

        con.Open();
        int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

        if (result > 0)
        {
            Response.Write("<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('1 Row added Successfully');</script");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('Please Select Product Image File');</script");
    }
}
```

Stack trace:

```
[SqlException (0x80131904): Must declare the scalar variable "@Name".]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +2440274
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +5765240
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +285
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +4169
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite) +948
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry) +286
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() +286
   Botswna_Centralized_Health_Card_System.registerPatient.registerPatient.onclickregiPatient(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Bow-t\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Botswna Centralized Health Card System\Botswna Centralized Health Card System\registerPatient\registerPatient.aspx.cs:140
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9767618
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +204
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +12
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +15
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1738
```

Comment: This is an ADO.NET error. The code you posted has nothing to do with ASP.NET

Comment: You attempt to *execute* the SQL twice. The first time is before you add *any* parameters to it.

Comment: remove first cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: You define all parameters as single character ASCII strings. I don't think that's what you wanted to do. You don't *close* the connection either. Check for any tutorial on ADO.NET and SqlCommand, you'll see that the connection is declared locally and placed in a `using` block to ensure it closes even if an error is thrown

Comment: ok i saw that..but is it the one that causing the error @Jilanipasha

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos alright i was following the other tutorial on how to submit an image to a database...then since i have to submit the image along with other data...i merged the code in one...so i was trying to submit both an image and other data to the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you are excuting query before adding parameter.

```
cmd = new SqlCommand(insertSQL, con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Name;
```

remove first `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Comment: he already have the `@Name` parameter so why he should add it again?

Comment: @Saif : No he has written `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` twice. one before adding parameter and one after. so he need to remove first statement.

Comment: @Saif Actually he is correct. OP executes the query before defining the parameters for the query. Exception will be thrown on the first scalar variable which just happens to be "Name". `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` should be called after the parameters have been initialised.

Comment: so he needs to comment the first ` cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` and everything would work.

Comment: @Saif Isnt that what Amit wrote in the answer?

Comment: alright i updated my code// i removed the cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() BUT i'm still having this error:  Must declare the scalar variable "@Name".

Comment: @RileyBow-t : which `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` did you remove? You need to remove first one, i.e just above one `cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Name;`

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` executed twice, so remove the first one as commented in this answer and declare it only once

```
 protected void onclickregiPatient(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con = new SqlConnection(conString);
        con.Open();


        if (FileUploadControl.HasFile)
        {
            string Name = txtName.Text;
            string surname = txtSurname.Text;
            string gender = genderRadio.Text;
            string dob = txtDob.Text;
            string dop = txtPob.Text;
            string nationality = txtNationality.Text;
            string birthcert = txtBirthCert.Text;
            string nationalid = txtNationalID.Text;
            string occupation = txtOccupation.Text;
            byte[] photo = FileUploadControl.FileBytes;
            string blood = DropDownList1.Text;
            string eye = eyeColor.Text;
            string skin = txtSkinColr.Text;
            string height = txtHeight.Text;
            string status = txtHivstatus.Text;
            string phone = txtPhone.Text;
            string posaddress = txtPosAddress.Text;
            string physicaladdress = txtPhyAddress.Text;
            string fullname = txtFullName.Text;
            string relationship = txtRelationship.Text;
            string phoneno = txtphoneNo.Text;
            string postal = postalAddres.Text;
            string physical = physicalAddress.Text;
            string radio = RadioButtonList1.Text;
            string type = txtType.Text;

            string insertSQL = ("insert into patientProfile values(@Name,@surname,@gender,@dob,@dop,@nationality,@birthcert,@nationalid,@occupation,@photo,@blood,@eye,@skin,@height,@status,@phone,@posaddress,@physicaladdress,@fullname,@relationship,@phoneno,@postal,@physical,@radio,@type)");
         cmd = new SqlCommand(insertSQL, con); 
           // cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); comment this line 


            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Name;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@surname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = surname;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@gender", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = gender;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@dob", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dob;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@dop", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dop;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@nationality", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = nationality;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@birthcert", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = birthcert;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@nationalid", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = nationalid;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@occupation", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = occupation;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@photo", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = photo;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@blood", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = blood;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@eye", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = eye;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@skin", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = skin;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@height", SqlDbType.Int).Value = height;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@status", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = status;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@phone", SqlDbType.Int).Value = phone;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@posaddress", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = posaddress;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@physicaladdress", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = physicaladdress;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@relationship", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = relationship;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@phoneno", SqlDbType.Int).Value = phoneno;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@postal", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = postal;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@physical", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = physical;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@radio", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = radio;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@type", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = type;


            con.Open();
            int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

            if (result > 0)
            {
                Response.Write("<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('1 Row added Successfully');</script");
            }

        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('Please Select Product Image File');</script");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Well, now you're going to get (presumably) a whole load of `NullReferenceException`s since you're accessing `cmd.Parameters` before `cmd` is initialized.

Comment: i did remove the first cmd execution....and updated my code but still facing the  "Must declare the scalar variable "@Name". error